# SOQL Query | Parent-To-Child Relationship

Tags: apex, soql

Eg. `SELECT Name, (Select FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account`

Why is the "Select" Under nested query not in capital letters?
or what will happen if I use in capital letter?

Comment: APEX is case insensitive so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!  the community here is more focused on working through specific problems rather than learning new concepts. Since you're completely new to Salesforce, I'd recommend working through [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex and SOQL are both case-insensitive. My personal formatting style is to use all caps for every query keyword as well as all Date literals, and to case each API Name correctly as well. But you could put that query in all lower case, all upper case, or any other mix of casing and it would be equally valid.